# Loop with addition clause

Tags: r, loops, addition, clause

I'd like to use loop (addition clause) to calculate the total number of casual renters (NOT data/observation) IF the season= 1 (season Spring). However, we are stuck with this problem.

Here is our code:

```
SpringCasualRenter <-rep(0,17379) for(i in 1:17379) { if(allData$season ==1 & allData$Casual.renter & i++) print(i)}
```

Total observations: 17379. 
#

Season: Spring 1, Summer 2, Autumn 3, Winter 4

Casual renter - number of non-registered user rentals initiated. Registered renter - number of registered user rentals initiated

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Hmm, there are several language-related mistakes here... For example, in R you don't use `i++`. You may want to read up on how `for`-loops work.

Comment: @Laterow Alright, thank you for the tip! Any idea what should we replace "i++" with?

Comment: With.. nothing? Currently it is in the `if` clause, so you are testing if `i++` is true, but given that `i++` doesn't mean anything in R, it will throw an error (probably about an unexpected `)` ). Again, I'd highly recommend just reading up on `for`-loops in R, since it seems to me that you are used to a different language and you might as well read up on `for`-loops properly.